# What does mod_pagespeed beacon do?

Tags: apache, module, mod-pagespeed

What is `mod_pagespeed` beacon?

I am getting a 404 error on Akamai on this.

I want to know why the module is being used.  I would be able to disable it if I knew what it was being used for.

Answer (score 2):

In servers where mod_pagespeed module is enabled, pages that are processed by this module send a sort of "ping" back to the server. The mod_pagespeed module is used to optimize, compress and cache media or content, so that your users get a better and faster experience on your server.

As far as I can tell, servers do not have to answer this "ping" for the PageSpeed module to work. As such, Akamai probably does not answer to this "ping".

I would advise **against** disabling PageSpeed module. I use it in all my servers and it really increases website performance.

Answer (score 0):

### [Beacon](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/faq#beacons)

Certain filters need to determine things about the page: in particular, the `lazyload_images`, `inline_preview_images`, and `inline_images` filters need to determine which images are above the fold, and the `prioritize_critical_css` filter needs to determine the CSS actually used by the page.

To do this, **the filters inject JavaScript into the rewritten HTML that analyzes the page in the browser and sends data back to mod_pagespeed using a POST method**. The default target is `/mod_pagespeed_beacon` but that can be changed using the `ModPagespeedBeaconUrl` directive.

### [Completely disable beacon](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/faq#control_beacons)

```
<Location /mod_pagespeed_beacon>
    Order allow,deny
</Location>
```